# Classes concept

Tags: java

I'm having trouble understanding what this means, and how it was coded

```
Foo number  = Foo.NUMBER;
```

Like, is Foo a class with static things?

(This was posted in an assignment it said "you might want to structure your solution like this")

Comment: Like, perhaps. It looks more like code for an enum to me.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, +1 And enums are static by default. :D

Comment: @mre: indeed they are! a worthless +1 back atcha! :D

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, Ouch..my feelings. :/

Comment: @mre: well, actually *all* points are worthless, since you can no longer redeem them for beer and pizza. Cheers!

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, Mmm...beer. Here, have another +1, cheers! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NUMBER` is `static` (and `final`) member of `Foo` class which return Foo object. Take a look at [java.awt.Color](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) class.

Comment: Why isn't there a Foo number = new Foo() or something like that?

Comment: @bb2, `Number` could be a static instance.

Comment: @bb2 With java.awt.Color, you may use **new** keyword to create an object or you may get instance directly from the defined static FIELDS.

Comment: This is not necessarily final.  If convention is followed it would be.  (because constants are in all caps, and must be final to not be reassigned)

Comment: @ nicholas.hauschild Yeh agree!

Answer (score 2):

```
class Foo {
   public static final Foo NUMBER = new Foo();
}
//later... 
Foo number = Foo.NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Hovercraft pointed out in the comments, it's worth noting that this syntax could (probably?) be referring to enums:

```
public enum Foo { NUMBER }

Foo number = Foo.NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo {
  public static Foo NUMBER = new Foo(); //might be final too...
  public Foo {
    // init Foo instance
  }
}
```

Here is an example of a class definition that will allow the line of code you posted to compile.  `Foo` is a class with a static member of type `Foo` identified by the name NUMBER.